# WPF Datagrid View (After Inserting Data into Cells explicitly when content scrolled Data loosing )

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

After Inserting Data into WPF datagrid cell Explicitly When content is scrolled the data loosing from the Cells

Data which I inserted disappears from cells

```
     <DataGrid AllowDrop="True" 
                  AlternatingRowBackground="White" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  Background="#FFDBF7FC" BorderBrush="#FF2374A0" 
                  BorderThickness="2" CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF041D31" 
                  Margin="17,173,0,-414" x:Name="DashBoardGrid" 
                  RowBackground="#FFDBF7FC" 
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                  VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF041D31" 
                  SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Width="929" />



int columnno = Convert.ToInt32(ColumnNo.Text); 
        int Finalcolumn = columnno - 1; 
        int count = DashBoardGrid.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            DataGridHelper.GetCell(DashBoardGrid, i, Finalcolumn).Content = AutofillValue.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using any Virtualization?

Comment: <DataGrid AllowDrop="True" AlternatingRowBackground="White" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Background="#FFDBF7FC" BorderBrush="#FF2374A0" BorderThickness="2" CanUserReorderColumns="True" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF041D31" Margin="17,173,0,-414" x:Name="DashBoardGrid" RowBackground="#FFDBF7FC" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"    VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF041D31" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="929" />

Comment: my CS Code

 int columnno = Convert.ToInt32(ColumnNo.Text);
                   int Finalcolumn = columnno - 1;

                    int count = DashBoardGrid.Items.Count;

                    // DashBoardGrid.Items[0].Cells[3].Text = "text";
                    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        DataGridHelper.GetCell(DashBoardGrid, i, Finalcolumn ).Content = AutofillValue.Text;

                    }

Comment: What is DataGridHelper? Can you post the code? You can edit and add code.

Comment: DataGridHelper class (Class is used to get the cell values and to assign the cell value for the particular cell)